# Knockout : limit number of characters in an observable field

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have an observable name field in my knockout view model.
Now i want to limit the number of characters in this field if it exceeds certain number.

As if name = "john smith" and i have a limit of 6 characters then
 display " john s... "

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Another reusable solution is to create a custom binding that displays a trimmed version of the text.

This allows the underlying value to remain unaffected, but trims the text for display purposes.  This would be useful for something like a message preview, or for fitting data into a grid column.

Example binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.trimLengthText = {};
ko.bindingHandlers.trimText = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var trimmedText = ko.computed(function () {
            var untrimmedText = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            var defaultMaxLength = 20;
            var minLength = 5;
            var maxLength = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().trimTextLength) || defaultMaxLength;
            if (maxLength < minLength) maxLength = minLength;
            var text = untrimmedText.length > maxLength ? untrimmedText.substring(0, maxLength - 1) + '...' : untrimmedText;
            return text;
        });
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, {
            text: trimmedText
        }, viewModel);

        return {
            controlsDescendantBindings: true
        };
    }
};
```

Use it like this:

```
<div data-bind="trimText: myText1"></div>
```

or...

```
<div data-bind="trimText: myText1, trimTextLength: 10"></div>
```

[**See Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/blugrasmaniac/8ypdX/4/)

Comment: I liked this solution; I just wish to suggest to put untrimmed text into element's title to provide a fast preview of original value; something like "element.title = untrimmedText;" if untrimmedText length is more than maxLength.

Comment: Just one small comment - it would be good idea to check that untimmed text's length is more than (trimTextLenth + 3), because if trimTextLenth equals 5, but text is "123456", result will be "12345...", which is longer than untrimmed version.

Comment: I have used Joseph's answer and Ivan's comment in this fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/8ypdX/90/ . This creates a variable called truncateText that allows you to define the text used for truncating, and measures the length of that variable.

If the trimmed text plus the truncation text is more than the original string then it doesn't perform the trim.

Answer (score 18):

```
<span data-bind="text: (name.length > 6 ? name().substring(0, 5) + '...' : name)"></span>
```

Or you can create a computed observable in your ViewModel, such as:

```
var self = this;

this.shortName = ko.computed(function() {
   return (self.name.length > 6 ? self.name().substring(0, 5) + '...' : self.name);
});
```

and then:

```
<span data-bind="text: shortName"></span>
```

Comment: I think in your first example you missed () after the first ```name```, as in: ```<span data-bind="text: (name().length > 6 ? name().substring(0, 5) + '...' : name)"></span>```

Comment: In Knockout you can use .length without having to evaluate the expression with ().

Answer (score 7):

Chris Dixon's solutions are perfect if you have one field that has a max length. But if you have to repeat this operation multiple times it becomes cumbersome. That is when you should write a custom observable extender, like this:

```
ko.extenders.maxLength = function(target, maxLength) {
    //create a writeable computed observable to intercept writes to our observable
    var result = ko.computed({
        read: target,  //always return the original observables value
        write: function(newValue) {
            var current = target(),
                valueToWrite = newValue ? newValue.substring(0, Math.min(newValue.length, maxLength)) : null;

            //only write if it changed
            if (valueToWrite !== current) {
                target(valueToWrite);
            } else {
                //if the rounded value is the same, but a different value was written, force a notification for the current field
                if (newValue !== current) {
                    target.notifySubscribers(valueToWrite);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    //initialize with current value to make sure it is rounded appropriately
    result(target());

    //return the new computed observable
    return result;
};
```

You can then use it on any observable, and you can specify a different maximum length for any of them. This removes the clutter from the HTML (solution 1), and the necessity to write a computed observable (solution 2). You simply define your observable the following way:

```
this.shortName = ko.observable().extend({ maxLength: 25 });
```

Comment: Just to be clear, when writing to (setting) the observable, this will truncate any values that exceed the maxLength, correct?

Comment: This solution does not limit the characters visible in the input.

Comment: I found a version that limits the visible characters too [here](https://www.rhyous.com/2015/10/26/handling-input-maxlength-using-knockout/)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to truncate the value for a numeric input you could use and extender that will truncate the value like the following:

```
ko.extenders.truncateValue = function(target, option) {                            
        target.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            if(newValue.length > option){
                target(newValue.substring(0,option));
            }                    
        });

        return target;
    };
```

And then create a custom binding that will will append the extender to the observable:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.maxLength = {
    init:  function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        'use strict';                     

        var maxlength = element.getAttribute("maxlength");

        valueAccessor().extend({truncateValue: maxlength })
        ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel);    
    }   
};
```

On your html you apply the maxLength binding as follows:

```
<input type="number" data-bind="maxLength: yourObservable" maxlength="9"></input>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure 'valueAccessor()' will return the value of 'maxLength' property not value of the observable you bound to the element.

Comment: @jmathew hope it makes more sense now with the edit, I added the html with the binding.

Comment: valueAccessor — A JavaScript function that you can call to get the current model property that is involved in this binding. Call this without passing any parameters (i.e., call valueAccessor()) to get the current model property value. To easily accept both observable and plain values, call ko.unwrap on the returned value.

Comment: Ah I see I thought your html would've looked like data-bind="value: yourObservable, maxLength:9". My mistake.